# i am trying to auto validate my c# application

Tags: c#

so far the application is working but i dont know how to auto validate, the user enters a number in a text box and the text box should never be empty when the user clicks button parse, any alternative suggestions as to how i can validate the application would be greatly appreciated

```
public Parse_Strings()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable;
}

private void Parse_Strings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void btn_exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void btn_parse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] temp = txtenter.Text.Split(",".ToCharArray());
    {
       if (temp.Length == 3)
       {
          txtname.Text = temp[0];
          txtaccount.Text = temp[1];
          txtpassword.Text = temp[2];
       }
       else if (temp.Length > 0)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(" cannot be empty ");
            }
            else if (temp.Length >= 3)
                 {
                   MessageBox.Show(" entry is above required range ");
                 }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us proper code. This code is incorrectly braced/formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make your validation in `Button Parse` click event ? Like this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtenter.Text) && 
       !(txtenter.Text.Replace(',' ,'').Any(x => char.IsLetter(x)))
{
     string[] temp = txtenter.Text.Split(',');
     ...

}
```